# slow performance- IIS or application?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, iis

Our team has an application in Android, with a .NET c# backend, hosted in IIS.
Recently, we have observed sudden and unexplainable latencies in our customers with the following scenario:

- Without any warning, users are enable to change the channel (Zapping) , since the product has to do with Live Media Streaming, and they can not even log out of the application
- The mobile application connected to another backend (still a c# backend) , is working properly, without any problem
- After some time (which varies from 6 hours of the first incident, to 5 minutes of the last one), it all turns back to normal.

I have enabled Failed Request Tracing logs, to see if I can get anything from there, and I have results as follows:

```
<failedRequest url="https://ourDNS.com:443/servertime.aspx"
               siteId="1"
               appPoolId="DefaultAppPool"
               processId="22232"
               verb="POST"
               remoteUserName=""
               userName=""
               tokenUserName="NT AUTHORITY\IUSR"
               authenticationType="anonymous"
               activityId="{80013C53-0802-B500-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
               failureReason="TIME_TAKEN"
               statusCode="200"
               triggerStatusCode="0"
               timeTaken="45141"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
```

The page described above is a simple page, that first gets the server's timezone, and then after getting the customer's timezone (that can be set manually from the client), returns the exact date and time of the device where the application is hosted, for further calculations of stream program, what is playing now etc. However, for this page, that returns a simple JSON with a string in it, it requires some times more than 45 seconds (to me this is insane).
Another log from Client side in the moment is one Exception as above:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:491)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
at com.framework.utilityframe.webhelper.HttpRequest.getHttpResponse(HttpRequest.java:316)
at com.framework.utilityframe.webhelper.HttpRequest.httpRequest(HttpRequest.java:393)
at com.tibo.webtv.web.TiboLog.logBufferingError(TiboLog.java:319)
at com.tibo.webtv.CustomVideoView$Buffering_Problem.doInBackground(CustomVideoView.java:324)
at com.tibo.webtv.CustomVideoView$Buffering_Problem.doInBackground(CustomVideoView.java:307)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Reading through different forums, I have seen different causes of performance leaks, starting from database to IIS and even a misconfiguration of the application. I have discarded database as a cause because:

- At the moment of the problem, database parameters were absolutely fine, no changes in queries time execution, no waiting tasks, no locking
- Secondly, the mobile and Decoder application connect to the same database, and the mobile application is running just fine with the same queries

Now, if I think of IIS, every Application hosted at that AppPool, was running fine and without delays, but still there may be something I am missing over there
And at least, something that makes me suspicious is the fact that the mobile application differs in two ways with the Decoder application:

- First, the mobile application takes the responses from the Backend in XML format, the Decoder uses JSON.
- Second,the mobile application uses http requests, and the Decoder uses https (SSL)

If anyone has experienced similar issues, their help would be greatly appreciated. And for any other detail you need, just ask and I will provide.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is in the software? It could just be a dodgy router between the server and the outside world, ip conflicts on the internal network, your isp that squishes the cable at times or any other network related issue. The logs you included are not directly pointing to software as the issue.

Comment: The clients are dispersed world-wide, and we have tried to connect the application in 2 different servers (both by the same hosting company), and in both requests, http and https. in all the situations we have had the same output, latency and problem in each one of the clients (around 10000 as we speak). What scares me the most is the fact that during this week, it has happened almost every day, and the fact that it starts and stops without any interference from our team, and without any warning

Comment: If its latency issues it makes me doubt even more about it being in the software. A easy way to test it is to write a small program that pings a remote computer every so often. Have the program log the latency and run it on your server for a day or so. With that log file you can either proof to your hosting company that they have a problem, or that it is not a networking issue. Alternatively (seeing as you have so many active users) you might want to look at the cpu / io usage on the server during peak hours. Perhaps the hardware is simply overloaded.

Comment: about CPU and IO usage, we have been monitoring them, and CPU is max 2% and ram does not go above 13GB (as it is in usual usage). About latency, I have installed a tool at the server (LeanSentry) and until now, it has not logged any issue, or problem related to the software or application (in fact, every IP registered with latency, are the ones of specific clients, which are known to have internet issues by their part). If there is any tool that we can use to monitor for internet problems, I am open to any advice.

Comment: What you collected is not yet enough to reveal the all aspects of the problem. Without full data from network layer, server side and client side at the same time, it would be almost impossible to correlate them and find out the cause. Don't use a forum for such cases, as it won't be able to handle such complicated cases.

Comment: I don't know LeanSentry personally but what I could gather from there website is that they monitor the hosting process. A useful tool to monitor the health of your application, but it does not seem to check how the application is connected to the outside world. As for ping tools I don't know if there are any existing. But with c# it would not be hard to write a application that pings every +-10 seconds to a external address (like the google dns at 8.8.8.8). Log the time of the time + latency to a text file. [ping example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb7xxkfx(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @LexLi actually, this Is just a first attempt of trying to find a cause, as this is the first time in 3 years we have this type of problem. And since my knowledge on server administration are very weak (I am a developer on the company who has been stuck with this problem), I am not very aware of what I should look about in someone who could really help me in the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, 
Today, our team made another test, which included :

- Application hosted in one server and database in another
- Application and database hosted in a completely different server (Azure environment)

In both cases, the result was the same: Latencies and problem at the service.
The problem was neither at the backend nor the server. First, the Java application by mistake executed Sync Tasks when saving the logs to another server(dedicated, with full potential to keep as much data as you can give). Second, the log server had a full HDD, with more than 1 TB of only DB Logs, so when the application executed those Sync Tasks (which came as the first call, before any interaction with the channels), they received the Socket exceptions. So, maybe for someone else who may see this post: PLEASE,ALWAYS CHECK YOUR TASKS IN YOUR APPLICATION,AND ALWAYS CHECK ANY SERVER RELATED TO YOUR APPLICATION!!! Thank you very much :D